# Magento 2 custom module not loading

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I installed a local copy of Magento 2 into my XAMPP and have been getting to know the new structure. I have however run into a problem when trying to setup a basic module.

I have created the following file/folder structure

```
app/code/Heirik/Test/etc/module.xml
```

Inside this file I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <module name="Heirik_Test" schema_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

I refreshed the store cache however when I go to store>configuration>advanced the module is not loading into the list. According to the most recent devdocs there is no longer a need to set the module to active inside the XML.

I know that Magento is reading the module.xml because if I remove the schema_version parameter I get an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the latest builds of Magento this has changed to

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Module_Name
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Nice update. I marked this as the correct answer as it accurately reflects the current build status.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, trial and error I located the following answer

For an existing Magento instance, you'll need to register a custom module as follows:

1. Edit the app/etc/config.php file and add your module there and specify value "1" (enabled)
2. Then refresh the cache.

So in my case I had to add

```
'Heirik_Test' => 1,
```

Into the Modules array inside app/etc/config.php

Comment: This is correct, but may be reworked before GA. The config.php file is relatively new. The modules array is in the required load order. The setup process works out the sequencing so at run time it just has to load the modules in the order of the array. So for now, yes, add your module to the array, but if your module must be loaded before another module you need to put it in the right place. We should make it nicer to add a new module without needing to manually editing config.php.

Comment: I recommend to not edit app/etc/config.php by hand as it is now possible to use php -f setup/index.php module-enable Heirik_Test which will sort the modules based on sequence (plus it's safer than editing manually).

Comment: @fooman at the time of original writing you were not able to. But now you are able to, but thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: @Eirik I know - just wanted to make sure that this information gets out there

Answer (score 1):

Or even easier, got to Mage install dir and run:

```
php -f setup/index.php module-enable --modules=MODULENAME
php -f setup/index.php update
```

Answer (score -1):

Your module's file named  `module.xml` file config tag should have XML schema and its xsd location which validate your `module.xml` file structure. Schema value should be like

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd"
```

Answer (score -1):

So my issue when trying to get a custom module to register, running Magento 2.2.0 was that the composer generated file `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php` was not updated when I ran composer update.

It didn't matter what I did, manually adding it to the `config.php` would make it look like it was working but after running `magento setup:upgrade` the module was no longer registered and didn't run any install/upgrade scripts.

After updating composer properly and tripple checking it was in the `autoload_files`, the module registered and I sighed of relief.

Just something to be aware of. Hopefully if anyone else has issues similar, this can shed some light.